# Event observer causes JSON error?

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, event-observer, extensions

I am writing a simple extension that is designed to capture the data from an order once it has been placed on Magento. However, any code I write to my observer appears to get passed to the browser as JSON and causes the site to hang at the checkout. I tested the code by simply echoing "Hello World" and it did indeed appear as JSON in the browser.

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0"  

Hello World"11"
```

app\code\Company\ServerSync\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="get_place_order" instance="Company\ServerSync\Observer\Order"/>
    </event>
```

app\code\Company\ServerSync\Observer\Order.php:

```
<?php

namespace Company\ServerSync\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Order implements ObserverInterface {

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to Magento, can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `echo` in your models. Only in templates basically.

In your case order submit using ajax call to `webapi` and `echo` output breaks down response data format.

You can test your observer using `debug` or logger as a last resort.